# Microfrontend Integration Issue: Module not found error when importing React child app into Next.js parent app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, micro-frontend

I am currently working on setting up a microfrontend architecture with a parent app using Next.js and a child app in React. Below are the key details of my configuration:

// webpack.config.js for React Child App

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const path = require("path");
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    port: 3001,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".jsx", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "child",
      filename: "remote.js",
      exposes: {
        "./App": "./src/App",
      },
      shared: {
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
        next: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["next"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      chunks: ["main"],
    }),
  ],
};
```

I'm following usual fol;der structure

- [App.js, index.js, ...] // Simple React app

Next.js Configuration (next.config.js):

// host/next.config.js

```
const { NextFederationPlugin } = require("@module-federation/nextjs-mf");

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack(config, { isServer }) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new NextFederationPlugin({
        name: "host",
        filename: "static/chunks/remoteEntry.js",
        remotes: {
          child: "child",
        },
        exposes: {},
      })
    );

    return config;
  },
};
```

and when i try tpo import React module in Nextjs application liek this

```
import Image from "next/image";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const HomePage = dynamic(() => import("child/App"), { ssr: false });

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <HomePage />
  );
}
```

I get this error

Module not found: Can't resolve 'child/App'

What could be causing this "Module not found" error, and how can I resolve it to successfully import the React child app into the Next.js parent app?

Answer (score 1):

need troubleshoort from different area, may be check the remote name is really "child" 1st.
In your Next.js configuration (next.config.js), check configured the remote as "child":

```
remotes: {
  child: "child",
},
```

Make sure that this name matches the name you've defined in the child application's webpack configuration (name: "child" in webpack.config.js). Double-check for typos or case sensitivity issues.
if not this area, then check Remote Entry Path, Remote Module Path...

Comment: thank you for your response. I've reviewed everything, but I'm still encountering the same error. I just want to confirm if Next.js and React with Module Federation work together. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.